# How to tune and use the MetaVolcanoR package

Tags: r, bioconductor, differential-expression, limma, meta-analysis

I conducted a differential expression analysis over several datasets, using `LIMMA`, each one on its own. For each dataset, I have a data frame of **all** the genes, with the LFC and the p-value. Those data frames are called `deg1`, `deg2`, `deg3` ... and so on.

I want to use the `MetaVolcanoR` package, using the `votecount_mv` approach since it is the only approach that I can pick the p-value and LFC thresholds that I desire.

The problem is I'm not sure how to tune the parameters. There are several problems that I'm facing and I would really use some help please:

How do I set the log fold change threshold if I want only `LFC > 0.5 and LFC < -0.5`?
Is it `log fold change = 0.5` ? just making sure.

What is the `metathr` parameter? I read about it and still don't understand what it does. I set it as 0.01 for now.

And the main problem, the plot is showing much more gene number than there actually is. You can see in `Dataset6` for example, the plot says it has over 50,000 genes while in reality, it has something like 18,000 genes. The same for Dataset8, why is this happening?

##### This is the plot:

[image]

##### This is my code:

```
totalDEG = list(Dataset1 = deg1, Dataset2 = deg2,
                Dataset3 = deg3, Dataset4 = deg4, Dataset5 = deg5, Dataset6 = deg6, 
                Dataset7 = deg7, Dataset8 = deg8 ,Dataset9 = deg9, Dataset10 = deg10,
                Dataset11 = deg11, Dataset12 = deg12, Dataset13 = deg13 , Dataset15 = deg15,
                Dataset16 = deg16, Dataset20 = deg20, Dataset21 = deg21)

totalDEG = map(totalDEG, ~ .x %>% rownames_to_column("symbol") %>% `row.names<-`(.$symbol))

meta_degs_vote <- votecount_mv(diffexp=totalDEG,
                               pcriteria='P.Value', 
                               foldchangecol='logFC',
                               genenamecol='symbol',
                               geneidcol=NULL,
                               pvalue = 0.05,
                               foldchange = 0.5, 
                               metathr=0.01,
                               collaps=FALSE,
                               jobname="MetaVolcano", 
                               outputfolder=".",
                               draw='HTML')

head(meta_degs_vote@metaresult, 50)
meta_degs_vote@degfreq
```

##### This is a small sample of the `deg13` dataframe, just as an example of how it looks:

```
structure(list(logFC = c(3.39094029649578, 2.91185452846888, 
-4.18752593306854, 4.15866027194434, -3.46058235630518, -2.87208933878881, 
-3.08172118179278, -2.7458737595494, -4.086372553458, -2.68889593085408, 
-3.03835320252487, 2.61330670793883, -2.48123655627091, 1.49263378072949, 
1.95754205818365, -2.70230318294949, -2.9154447157702, -3.38110311321268, 
-2.35284609598761, -3.61327208834916, 2.03692346164301, -1.70931971282814, 
2.27925549238084, -3.79524834465106, 1.64515339181668, -4.30959811283984, 
3.57930610863801, -2.54394115096987, -1.98143797060853, 4.03178891878422
), AveExpr = c(6.4934411845873, 6.79507589173635, 3.87626322696796, 
5.02990511836996, 3.37154863566726, 4.54352970704667, 2.51617183960423, 
5.36760482831628, 8.74162861573995, 3.52708473144296, 1.56671205994866, 
5.87684931921495, 4.44218678637856, 5.12219572880673, 7.17539095745285, 
3.53733757517713, 3.35148844504943, 5.15160050823647, 4.75910049955374, 
2.76067393839851, 7.59404366884022, 3.26758602409262, 6.6742932845645, 
2.02865432630183, 7.35343444625846, 1.63566796485655, 6.63046957559406, 
4.0296762052982, 5.52320581646106, 5.21519413005468), t = c(7.67283765970783, 
7.48874311179818, -6.82705440075341, 6.17183091062419, -6.04487485029223, 
-5.8487763400982, -5.92000790680834, -5.64958317461715, -5.61111489307273, 
-5.58440722941211, -5.78651741270403, 5.34175048353288, -5.31088208376663, 
5.08100365503679, 5.03973023175764, -5.07773225272668, -5.04632997176375, 
-4.96736474738699, -4.82583305184561, -4.92525789154973, 4.78892270501915, 
-4.75294466621978, 4.64502680172295, -4.88600418339975, 4.62243262623093, 
-4.78866983562446, 4.56376665911121, -4.57063797766699, -4.48421852802591, 
4.47493043300733), P.Value = c(8.61557824744483e-06, 1.08572492426076e-05, 
2.57808593137873e-05, 6.41321288302935e-05, 7.70283126846018e-05, 
0.000102673342223582, 9.24388613776644e-05, 0.000138234657017388, 
0.000146500473045098, 0.000152546919410067, 0.000112607650587545, 
0.000221306832937214, 0.000232172444273951, 0.000333174926637586, 
0.000355778600664596, 0.000334909952712188, 0.000352058129044564, 
0.000399405716020234, 0.000501862041539822, 0.000427357183393412, 
0.000532900955175219, 0.000565105101377844, 0.000674574457630558, 
0.000455275577064366, 0.000700192843853878, 0.000533120436605821, 
0.000771595292301189, 0.000762850982694916, 0.00088083209108589, 
0.000894604612049976), adj.P.Val = c(0.105689892752164, 0.105689892752164, 
0.167309183326708, 0.24749466449955, 0.24749466449955, 0.24749466449955, 
0.24749466449955, 0.24749466449955, 0.24749466449955, 0.24749466449955, 
0.24749466449955, 0.322868951254968, 0.322868951254968, 0.364560714544159, 
0.364560714544159, 0.364560714544159, 0.364560714544159, 0.388801494259897, 
0.397198753468022, 0.396200809689826, 0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 
0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 
0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022, 0.397198753468022
), B = c(3.51320342275366, 3.35460378796296, 2.44903607778273, 
1.62363531926393, 1.57839963166078, 1.44388223679157, 1.36898233186455, 
1.24528027435772, 1.14177006290097, 1.04403303682497, 0.945243757754988, 
0.859404654981856, 0.797031901979986, 0.496397382158138, 0.450148400219772, 
0.418557695883232, 0.3417613688148, 0.324284286390148, 0.136478287041671, 
0.0982449107580958, 0.0925437909507512, -0.0280517206307875, 
-0.112494849608916, -0.129424832005619, -0.147717311976667, -0.200056933894112, 
-0.234222113297706, -0.244412573722838, -0.351160223852428, -0.386270016806261
)), row.names = c("FOS", "DUSP1", "TP53AIP1", "FOSB", "TFAP2C", 
"KIF26A", "GRHL3", "CTAGE4", "FCGBP", "FBXO27", "AC087289.3", 
"SH3BP5", "GABRE", "ADAMTS4", "DDHD1", "KCNS3", "ARHGEF16", "SERINC2", 
"OPLAH", "WNT7B", "GSN", "OVOL2", "CD163", "SVOPL", "ZFP36", 
"SPESP1", "FGD5", "FAAH", "ERBB3", "PARM1"), class = "data.frame")
```